# SUBQUERY to sum up rows

Tags: mysql, sql

The following result is created from a SELECT statement I've created:

```
total           date        currency    provider    conversion_to_usd
170.0168890000  2012-01-01  AUD         Telluride    1.06694
177.5532500000  2012-01-01  CAD         Telluride    1.00030
33.1864000000   2012-01-01  NZD         Telluride    0.82966
687.4900000000  2012-01-01  USD         Telluride    1.00000
```

How would I sum up the rows sales here, for example 170.016*1.066 + 177.55*1.00...

```
SELECT SUM(...) FROM <SELECT STATEMENT ABOVE> ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the `SELECT` statement an **alias**.

This will then allow you to refer to the columns `total` and `conversion_to_usd`, to use their values on the `SUM`, thus, performing the required calculations:

```
SELECT SUM(t.total*t.conversion_to_usd) FROM (SELECT STATEMENT ABOVE) t
```